# Drupal 8: Intercepting a 404 route and setting to code to 200

Tags: drupal-8

In a Drupal 8 site, /some/random/path will return "404 not found". At runtime, I need to intercept some of these paths and set them to return something valid.

I added a file called `MYMODULE.services.yml`:

```
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\MYMODULE\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Then, in ./src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php, I have:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('system.404')) {
      $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\MYMODULE\Controller\MyController::load');
    }
  }
}
```

Then in ./src/Controller/SpokeController.php, I have:

```
class SpokeController extends ControllerBase {

  public function load() {
    $path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

    if (path_is_valid()) { // I can only do this at runtime.
      // Is there a way to add something here like:
      // $this->setResponseCode(200);
      // return a render array for the content.
    }
    else {
      // return a render array like "page not found".
    }
  }

}
```

In my controller, can I change the response code from 404 to 200? (I am expecting something like `$this->setResponseCode(200)` to exist, but I can't find it.)

Answer (score 1):

[This change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2549159) explains how to achieve this:

In SpokeController::load(), we can return a render array which contains the following:

```
$render['#attached']['http_header'][] = ['Status', "200"];
```

That changes the status code.

To change the title dynamically, you can add the following line to alterRoutes():

```
$route->setDefault('_title_callback', '\Drupal\steward_spoke\Controller\SpokeController::title');
```

Then, return a title in SpokeController::title(). All this together lets you return a title, content, and status code for a route dynamically.